# Cardinal numbers with NumberFormatter using Locale settings in Swift

Tags: swift, locale, number-formatting, nsnumberformatter, cardinality

How can I generate cardinal numbers`(One, Two, Three)` using `NumberFormatter` in Swift using Locale settings.

For example, I am able to convert `1 minute -> One minute` using English `Locale` settings. But for Norwegian it should be **Et minutt**, While it translates to **En minutt** which is wrong.
Norwegian translation for `One` is `En` but when we use it in some sentence, sometimes it should be `Et`.
Here is sample of my code.

```
let measurement = Measurement(value: 1, unit: UnitDuration.minutes)
let measurementFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
measurementFormatter.unitStyle = .long
measurementFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "nb_no")
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "nb_no")
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
measurementFormatter.numberFormatter = formatter
let result = measurementFormatter.string(from: measurement)
```

**Output:**

`én minutt`

**Expected Output**

`et minutt`

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746121/how-to-handle-special-cases-in-localization-swift.

Comment: Yeah this can solve my problem for now but I was looking for some solution using `Formatters` so that my solution can be a generic one.

Comment: Same with the German language: "eins Minute" instead of the correct "Eine Minute". – Interesting problem!

Comment: Same with russian language: "один минута" instead of "одна минута", and "два минуты" instead of "две минуты". And ukrainian and belarusian too. Formatting for 1 and 2 is wrong.

Comment: My guess would be that the MeasurementFormatter  in combination with spellout style does not support correct gender/plural, and the "Plural Rule Properties" in a stringsdict file are your only choice. See e.g. "Plural and Gender Support" in https://www.objc.io/issues/9-strings/string-localization/

Comment: DateComponentsFormatter has the same problem.