# Swift Switch Statement

Tags: swift, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm rather new to programming and was wondering if there's a more concise way to accomplish the grammatical edits towards the end (ensuring that it doesn't return nonsensical statements like 1 bottleS) than what I've done here? I was thinking maybe a switch statement, but I am not familiar enough to implement one or even sure if that's the best approach. Thanks!

```
func beerSong(withThisManyBottles totalNumberOfBottles : Int) -> String { 

    var lyrics : String = ""    

    for i in (3...totalNumberOfBottles).reversed() {

        let newLine : String = "\n \(i) bottles of beer on the wall, \(i) bottles of beer. \n Take one down and pass it around, \(i - 1) bottles of beer on the wall.\n"

        lyrics += newLine

} 

lyrics += "\n 2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer. \n Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of beer on the wall.\n"

lyrics += "\n 1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer. \n Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.\n" 

lyrics += "\n No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer. \n Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.\n"

return lyrics

}

print(beerSong(withThisManyBottles : 99))
```

Comment: This is a really good start for a new programmer :) Great work! My answer might be a bit complex, but it's really flexing Swift's muscles to show how this could be most concisely/idiomatically/maintainably written. If you have any question, feel free to ask! :)

Comment: Another way to get the grammatically correct phrase is a “localization file with plural rules” – Not only the British drink . See for example  [How to handle special cases in localization swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42746121/1187415).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on it. rmaddy's code computes `beerBottleLine(for:)` twice for most numbers (once when the number is the "main" number, and once again when it's the "one less" number). Admittedly, it's an absolutely tiny and essentially meaningless performance difference, but it demonstrates the use of the neat `zip(a, a.dropLast())` pattern.

I also opted to increase readability by taking advantage of multiline string literals, switching to more conventional identifier names, and by using a switch rather than 3 part `if`/`else if`/`else` ladder.

```
func bottlePhrase(for count: Int) -> String {
    switch count {
        case 0: return "no more bottles of "
        case 1: return "1 bottle"
        case _: return "\(count) bottles"
    }
}

func beerSong(bottleCount: Int) -> String {
    let bottlePhrases = (0...bottleCount)
        .lazy
        .reversed()
        .map{ bottlePhrase(for: $0) + " of beer" }

    let mainBody = zip(bottlePhrases, bottlePhrases.dropFirst())
        .map { bottlePhrase, oneLessBottlePhrase in return """
            \(bottlePhrase) on the wall, \(bottlePhrase).
                Take one down and pass it around, \(oneLessBottlePhrase) on the wall.

            """
        }
        .joined(separator: "\n")

    return mainBody + """
        \nNo more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.
            Go to the store and buy some more, \(bottleCount) bottles of beer on the wall.
        """
}

print(beerSong(bottleCount: 5))
```

Comment: Clever. I like it. Good use of Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm a little torn between using `\n` and actual blank lines, within multi-line literals. The former looks cluttered, but clearly expresses intent, while the latter is clearer, but could come off as incidental (even though it should be expected of Swift devs to know blank lines matter within a MLSL). What do you think?

Comment: I'm far from an expert on such subtleties but I would think one of the reasons to use MLSL is to format the string more naturally into its multiple lines. Using \n in an MLSL kind of misses the point of the MLSL I think. That might make a good question for code review.

Comment: @Alexander I was hoping to get to see a switch statement used to solve this! I just picked up Swift about a week ago, so there's still a lot I am unfamiliar with. Can you explain the `.lazy` and `.map` portions in more detail? Also, how exactly does the `zip(a, a.dropLast())` work?

Comment: @Maddy https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/higher-order-functions-in-swift-filter-map-reduce-flatmap-1837646a63e8

Comment: This explains the zip/dropFirst trick better than I can https://repl.it/repls/AnnualColorlessButton

Comment: @Maddy If you want to learn about `switch`, read all about them in the Swift book in the [Control Flow chapter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID127)

Answer (score 1):

I would write a method to return the proper wording based on a number:

```
func bottles(for count: Int) -> String {
    if count == 0 {
        return "no more bottles"
    } else if count == 1 {
        return "1 bottle"
    } else {
        return "\(count) bottles"
    }
}
```

Then I would refactor your `beerSong` method as:

```
func beerBottleLine(for count: Int) -> String {
    let countBottles = bottles(for: count)
    let oneLess = bottles(for: count - 1)
    let line = "\(countBottles) of beer on the wall, \(countBottles) of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, \(oneLess) of beer on the wall."

    return line
}

func beerSong(withThisManyBottles totalNumberOfBottles : Int) -> String {
    let lyrics = (1...totalNumberOfBottles).reversed().map { beerBottleLine(for: $0)}.joined(separator: "\n")

    return lyrics + "\nNo more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.\nGo to the store and buy some more, \(totalNumberOfBottles) bottles of beer on the wall."
}
```

And a quick test:

```
print(beerSong(withThisManyBottles: 5))
```